# Running/Compiling binaries that require boost 1.58 on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, boost

I'm hoping that I won't have to rebuild a recent server that is running Ubuntu server 18.04...

It's running great but there is one app that kicks out this error when I try to run it:

> error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I've searched various places and tried to manually install boost 1.58 but it always fails on dependancies and reverts to 1.65

Is there a way to get 1.58 installed, or if necessary to recompile from source using a newer boost version..?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the necessary boost 1.58 packages form the xenial repository to keep things built against 16.04 running in 18.04, or you will have to rebuild against the newer libboost that is in 18.04, yes.

Comment: Yeah i tried installing from a .deb file but it seems to fail because all the dependencies are the wrong versions...

I just tried to re-compile but it gives this error:
>configure: error: Detected LibreSSL: This is NOT supported, and may break consensus compatibility!

Comment: I've now just tried adding the xenial repository and installing boost 1.58 and it looks like its running!!!